# Fetch Single Number using Preg_Match

Tags: php, regex

```
    <span class="nowrap">
        <span class="use_sprites stars4 stars4i5" title="5 start hotel">&nbsp;
    </span>
```

I need to fetch the single number 5 that is in between title.

Here is my attempt:

```
preg_match_all('#<span class="nowrap">\s*(.*?)\s*<\/span>#s', $htmlOfPage, $rate);
```

The above code fetches the following:

```
<span class="use_sprites stars4 stars4i5" title="5 start hotel">&nbsp;
```

***Question:***

- Starting point: `<span class="nowrap">`
- Ending point: `</span>`
- Target section: `title="5 start hotel"`
- Target value: `the single number in between title`

**I need to start from Starting point and ignore everything except title="..." and in title grab the single number. By now, we already at the end point.**

Any help how to do the above steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = '<span class="nowrap">
        <span class="use_sprites stars4 stars4i5" title="5 start hotel">&nbsp;
    </span>';

preg_match('/<span class="nowrap">.+? title="([0-9]){1}/sm', $str, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span class="nowrap">
        <span class="use_sprites stars4 stars4i5" title="5
    [1] => 5
)
```

Make sure you look at the source code for the match.  It will not show up in the browser window because of the span tags

That should just match the number you are looking for

Comment: Cheers ... Can you please briefly explain what do s and m do?

Comment: Actually, I guess all you need is the m option for multi-line mode http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html

Comment: It didn't work. There are spaces and new lines after "> ... I also tried '/<span class="nowrap">\s*.+?title="([0-9]{1})"/sm' ... Didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change `title="([0-9]{1})"` to `title="([0-9]{1}).*?"` would be my guess off the top of my head

Comment: @user311509  Updated.. try that

Comment: preg match returns an array.  $match[1] is what you need.  Works fine on my server running php5

Comment: `([0-9]){1,}` matches one or more digits, but captures only the last digit.  It's not a problem in this case (I've never heard of a 10-star hotel),  but you obviously meant `([0-9]+)`: *match and capture one or more digits*.

Comment: Unfortunately, i found that the code doesn't work as it should. The page has many block of spans that has title in it. If i do $match[4], etc. I get blank. I should get 19 array values.

Comment: Based on my original preg_match, i added another line:

preg_match_all('#\s*title="([0-9]+)"\s*#s', $rate[1][0], $rate2);

I get 0 results! I don't any reason why i'm getting no results!